# Browserify working with grunt ReacjJS and yii2 vendor path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gruntjs, yii2, browserify

**Background**

I'm trying to setup a Yii2 project with Browserify to manage JS dependancies. As Yii2 places JS and CSS dependancies in the `vendor/bower` directory, i'm trying to configure Browserify to use this as the include path for vendor dependancies.

I have a Grunt task setup to run my js build.

**Problem**

When I try to compile my js files using the Grunt task I am getting an error trying to find `React` (the first include in my js project).

`Error: Cannot find module 'react' from '{my-working-directory}/modules/contact/asset/js'`

**Code**

I have React installed (bower install) and available in my `vendor/bower` directory. My project JS src files i'm trying to build are located in `modules/contact/asset/js/`. In my JS files i'm including React at the top of the file.

**modules/contact/asset/js/main.jsa**

```
var React = require('react');

var component = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
       ...
    }
});

...
```

I have setup my Grunt browserify task with the include paths so that browserify knows how to find my includes, I have additionally added the react transform so that the JSX gets compiled into js.

**Gruntfile.js**

```
...

browserify: {

    options: {
        transform: [ require('grunt-react').browserify ], 

        browserifyOptions: {
            paths: [
                './vendor/bower/',
                './modules/contact/asset/js/'
            ]
        }
    },

    client: {
        src: [
            './modules/contact/asset/js/*.js'
        ],
            dest: './modules/contact/web/js/main.min.js'
    }
},

...
```

**Question**

Why is browserify not able to find react or other includes?

Answer (score 0):

You can't and should't access to `vendor` directory from web. If your website loaded from `web` folder, then you can only access only files and folders in `web` directory.

You can use `AssetBundle` to register scripts from `vendor/bower` directory:

```
class ReactAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $sourcePath = '@bower';
    public $js = [
        'react/react.js'
    ];
}
```

See more [in documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html).

Comment: My issue is before this step (build time not run time), so I should be able to access vendor/bower. I'm precompiling a single js file using browserify  and placing it in the web directory `/modules/contact/web/js/main.min.js`, then loading it the way you mentioned.